# How do i submit upload a file to a url and get back xml via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I created a form that uploads a file to a url which will analyze the file and send back xml but the xml is displayed on the browser. Is there a way to upload a file to a url and get back xml using ajax so i can parse it and display result to user?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file

Comment: If you want ajax you need to make `XMLHttpRequest`. Using a form-submit is not ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You need to upload the file using AJAX in order to receive an AJAX response. This plugin is quite handy to do that: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.